# SQL Merge Statement delete from another table before delete

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-delete

I have a table:StudentHome which has a fk-constraint to the student table. So when the student gets deleted, I also need to delete the record from the StudentHome. When I used the plain delete statement, I wrote

```
Insert into Student 
select studentId, (other fields) from #Student

Delete sh
from StudenHome sh
left join #Student temps on temps.StudentId = sh.fkStudentId
where temps.studentId is null

Delete s
from Student s
left join #Student temps on temps.StudentId = s.studentId
where temps.studentId is null
```

However, I am when I try to use the merge statement, I am unsure how to delete records from studenthome before I delete from the student table.

```
merge into Student s
using #Student temps
on s.StudentID = temps.StudentId
when not matched by target then
insert ...
when not matched by source then

-- Delete from StudentHome 
delete;
```

Is there a way to implement the above sudo code where I delete from the table:StudentHome before I delete from the student table?

Comment: The normal behaviour is to specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` or similar in the table's definition (then any delete on that table will cascade and delete any rows that refer to it).  The exact answer depends on which database you're using.

Comment: Did you check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? *WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE ... THEN <merge_matched>* and below: *<merge_matched>::=  { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | **DELETE** }*

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to explicitly delete from two tables within a single statement. However, you can simply use two merge statements to get something equivalent to your two delete statements. (Or even just use a delete statement for the first part if that's easier.)

```
merge into StudentHome sh
using #Student temps
on sh.fkStudentId = temps.StudentId
when not matched by source then
delete;

merge into Student s
using #Student temps
on s.StudentID = temps.StudentId
when not matched by target then
insert ...
when not matched by source then
delete;
```